# repetition quantifier grepl

Tags: r, regex, grepl

i am trying to check whether a string contains 2 or more date values

given string contains four date values but grepl returns FALSE

cant get grepl to detect all date instances in strng

```
> strng
[1] "SMART PRODUCTS 0.50 0.76 0.79 05/09/16 1000 1.02 1.02 27/06/16 17/06/11 27/06/16 0"
> grepl("([0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]){1}", strng)
[1] TRUE
> grepl("([0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]){2,}", strng)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Try `grepl("(.*[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9].*){2,}", x)`; your second pattern is searching for two consecutive occurrences, e.g. `grepl("([0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]){2,}", "27/06/1617/06/11")`.

Comment: You may want to look at function `str_locate_all( )` in the stringr package.  and the stringi package also provides similar functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `([0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]){1}` pattern actually can find 4 occurrences: `05/09/16`, `27/06/16`, `17/06/11`, `27/06/16`.

Now, when you try to set a limiting quantifier to match 2 or more occurrences, the *whole group* should match 2 or more times of the pattern *at a stretch*. It is the same as quantifying a simple pattern like `a`: `a{2,}` will find `aaa` in `baaac`, but won't find any match in `bacada`.

Thus, you need to be able to match anything before the required pattern and put it into the quantified group. The easies way here is to use lazy dot matching (`.*?`) that will match any 0+ chars but as few as possible):

```
(.*?[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]){2,}
 ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Om0GE8/1) that will not find any match in `SMART PRODUCTS 0.50 0.76 0.79 17/06/11 0`, but will match the string in question.

NOTE: If you are using the regex in `grepl` without `perl=TRUE`, it is a TRE regex, and `.` will match any char including linebreak characters. If you use `perl=TRUE`, a dot will not match linebreak characters, you will need to add `(?s)` at the pattern start to enforce the same behavior for a dot.